# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

I fail to understand why this simple line of code won't work. This was working in demo`.js` file but not working in actual `shopify` environment.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        console.log('click');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: {{ 'PincodeCommaSeparated.txt' | asset_url }},
            dataType : "text",   //error here
            success: function (data) { GetPinCodeData(data); }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: What's being interpolated by `{{ 'PincodeCommaSeparated.txt' | asset_url }}`?

Comment: @gcampbell //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0732/1419/t/12/assets/PincodeCommaSeparated.txt?5676684146368892424

Comment: You probably need to wrap it in quotes.

Comment: @gcampbell - did not work

Comment: Does it say what the unexpected token is?

Comment: @gcampbell, it doesnt say anything about it